# Ponteiro Void em C

Tags: c, ponteiro, void

> Escreva um programa em C que leia 2 números (inteiro ou real) e
>   imprime a soma deles. O usuário informará qual o tipo de dado que será digitado.
>   Obs: Use somente ponteiros e alocação dinâmica de memória para resolver o
>   problema.

Eu tenho este exercício para resolver e acabei fazendo desta maneira, o resultado sai conforme esperado, porém, não sei se foi feito da maneira que deveria ser feito.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()  {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    int op;
    int i1, i2;
    float r1,r2;
    void *x1, *x2;

    printf("M E N U  D E  I N F O R M A Ç Õ E S\n");
    printf("1-Inteiro\n");
    printf("2-Float\n");
    scanf("%d", &op);

    switch(op) {
    case 1 :
        printf("Digite o primeiro número inteiro: ");
        scanf("%d", &i1);
        x1 = (int *)malloc((i1 * sizeof(int)));
        x1 = &i1;
        printf("Digite o segundo número inteiro: ");
        scanf("%d", &i2);
        x2 = (int *)malloc((i2 * sizeof(int)));
        x2 = &i2;

        printf("%d", i1 + i2);
        break;
    case 2 :
        printf("Digite o primeiro número real: ");
        scanf("%f", &r1);
        x1 = (float *)malloc((r1 * sizeof(float)));
        x1 = &r1;
        printf("Digite o segundo número real: ");
        scanf("%f", &r2);
        x2 = (float *)malloc((r2 * sizeof(float)));
        x2 = &r2;
        printf("%.2f", r1 + r2);
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Não tem o menor sentido você alocar memória, colocar o endereço da memória alocada em um ponteiro e  a seguir fazer este ponteiro apontar para o endereço de outra variável. Também não vejo sentido em alocar um ponteiro do tipo void pois você precisa saber para que um ponteiro está apontando (uma caractere um int de 32 bits ou de 64 bits, um float, um double, etc), estude sobre aritmética de ponteiros.

Comment: Tenta fazer sem `i1`, `i2`, `r1`, nem `r2` e sem acrescentar outras variaveis, apenas com o que fica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O código que você escreveu faz algumas coisas que não tem sentido. Observe por exemplo esta linha:

```
x1 = (int *)malloc((i1 * sizeof(int)));
```

Aqui cria espaço para tantos inteiros quanto o número que está em `i1`. Significa que se a pessoa inserir `10` está a criar espaço para `10` inteiros, como se fosse um array, reservando normalmente `40` bytes seguidos em memoria.

Mas logo de seguida tem isto:

```
x1 = &i1;
```

Aqui colocou o ponteiro que acabou de criar com 40 bytes livres(exemplo) a apontar para a variável `i1`. Então perdeu o acesso à memoria previamente alocada e criou um vazamento de memoria.

---

O enunciado é meio vago, mas seguindo a restrição à letra de apenas poder usar ponteiros e alocação dinamica, podia fazer assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()  {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    int *op, *i1, *i2;
    float *r1, *r2;

    printf("M E N U  D E  I N F O R M A Ç Õ E S\n");
    printf("1-Inteiro\n");
    printf("2-Float\n");
    op = malloc(sizeof(int));
    scanf("%d", op);

    switch(*op) {
    case 1 :
        printf("Digite o primeiro número inteiro: ");
        i1 = malloc(sizeof(int));
        scanf("%d", i1);

        printf("Digite o segundo número inteiro: ");
        i2 = malloc(sizeof(int));
        scanf("%d", i2);

        printf("%d", *i1 + *i2);
        break;
    case 2 :
        printf("Digite o primeiro número real: ");
        r1 = malloc(sizeof(float));
        scanf("%f", r1);

        printf("Digite o segundo número real: ");
        r2 = malloc(sizeof(float));
        scanf("%f", r2);

        printf("%.2f", *r1 + *r2);
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Veja a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/x123N7)

Repare que nesta versão, quando leio o primeiro inteiro, primeiro aloco espaço na memoria, e guardo o local onde ficou reservada a memoria para esse numero:

```
i1 = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

Depois faço a leitura com `scanf` diretamente para esse local:

```
scanf("%d", i1);
```

Como tenho um ponteiro não foi necessário utilizar o operador `&` para obter o endereço.

No final tenho apenas 5 ponteiros no `main` e todos alocados dinamicamente com `malloc`. Este código não faz muito sentido na vida real, mas cumpre com os requisitos do enunciado, que eu suspeito que sejam para forçar a prática de ponteiros e alocação dinamica.

Também não vejo onde entram os ponteiros de `void` que menciona no titulo da pergunta, mas existem inúmeras formas de resolver este exercício.